# Upgrading distro generates new and different boot images

Tags: grub, boot-loader, disk-image

I dual-boot Windows and Fedora on a machine with GRUB. Whenever I update Fedora or its Linux kernel, it generates a new disk image in `/boot` thus creating another boot option when loads GRUB. However, Arch Linux on another machine whenver I update the distro or its kernel, there's no change in `/boot`.

Forgive me if I have a flawed understanding of how this works; when the Linux kernel or distro get updated and a new boot image gets updated, wouldn't that mean previous versions of the image are essentially deprecated, shouldn't they just be deleted (hence replaced by its updated counterpart)?

Why does a new and different image generate in `/boot`? Is it safe to simply delete previous versions?

Comment: It is a safe-keeping measure in case something goes wrong. You can always delete the old version manually.

Comment: Also, Arch is the DIY of distro's.  The behavior you describe for Fedora is part of the distro.  Arch probably has an excellent wiki page telling you how to do the same thing.  The difference is that when you do it the Arch way, you've done it and understand it, where Fedora does it for you.  Two different approaches, better depends on your goals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sub>I thank [Rui F Riberio](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/419194/upgrading-distro-generates-new-and-different-boot-images#comment753155_419194) for the information.</sub>

The boot images of previous kernel versions can be removed by deleting `initramfs-X.XX.XX` and `vmlinuz-X.XX.XX`. After that, I update GRUB with

```
# grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/efi/EFI/fedora/grub.cfg
```